# Kirby: MarkdownExtra doesn't produce wanted paragraphes, renders line-breaks instead

Tags: markdown, kirby

I'm currently getting my head around http://getkirby.com and am very pleased to far. I activated [Markdown Extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/) which comes shipped with Kirby so I can use Markdown within div-elements.

This works pretty well until the point where I need to create separate paragraphes of text, like so:

```
<div class="my-class" markdown="1">
    This is the first paragraph

    This is the second paragraph
</div>
```

Instead of rendering it like this:

```
<div class="my-class">
    <p>This is the first paragraph</p>

    <p>This is the second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I get this result:

```
<div class="my-class">
    <p>This is the first paragraph<br />
    This is the second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Is this wanted behavior I can control or is there something wrong with the parser?

Thanks for your help up front.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I have the [same question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005188/paragraphs-inside-div-with-markdown-extra)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. But the issue is already known: https://github.com/erusev/parsedown-extra/issues/18

Comment: The main contributor just fixed the issue! BTW, you have to update both the original parsedown and the parsedown-extra PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed by the developer (https://github.com/erusev/parsedown-extra/issues/18), I've created a pull request for it https://github.com/getkirby/kirby/pull/132