# paragraphs inside div with parsedown

Tags: php, html, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

### How do I create paragraphs inside a `<div markdown="1">` using [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/)?

For instance, look at the following code.

#### Input

```
<div markdown="1">
Lorem ipsum, blah blah blah...\n

Another Lorem ipsum, blah blah blah...
</div>
```

#### Output

```
<div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum, blah blah blah...\n

Another Lorem ipsum, blah blah blah...
</p>
</div>
```

Why is markdown-extra creating one large `<p>` for the entire contents of the div?

How do I create newlines since this does not work?

Possible duplicate: [Kirby: MarkdownExtra doesn't produce wanted paragraphes, renders line-breaks instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672935/kirby-markdownextra-doesnt-produce-wanted-paragraphes-renders-line-breaks-ins)

Useful tester: http://parsedown.org/extra/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the parser. You should report it at https://github.com/erusev/parsedown-extra/issues.

Comment: Um... Didn't you create parsedown-extra? I just looked and it seems that its been reported already. I added a comment to the issues thread. For now, what should I do for newlines?

Comment: @HelpingHand, I just updated Parsedown. The update should resolve your issue.

Comment: I just used it... and... it still isn't working... Has the method of implementation changed at all?

Comment: @HelpingHand, You need to update both `Parsedown.php` and `ParsedownExtra.php`.

Comment: Yup... It worked! I was going batty restarting my entire system just to see if it was something that I was doing. Thank you for the help! Great piece of software.

Comment: @HelpingHand, You are welcome. I saw that you started a wiki about Parsedown Extra. I appreciate that.

Comment: No problem... I felt that the existing documentation on markdown language was a little complicated for the average web user. Its definitely a work in progress. Thanks for the script that makes it all happen! :)